# Conditional comparison

Tags: plsql, conditional-statements

Given one table T1 with 100 rows and A,B,C,D as columns .

I need to check that C and D are equal in case A and B are both 1. Could anyone provide me the SQL code for this?

Comment: Pl make sure that the A and B that are 1 is for diff rows not at the same row.It is helpful if u give the code ."Expert pl can u help in the mentioned issue.
Have one table T1 with 100 rows with A,B,C,D 4 columns .

Need to compare when A=1 and B=1 and at the same time,the row of A (ie)equal to 1 and the row of B (ie)equal to 1 their C and D columns should be equal .
Pl mention the Pl/Sql query  .
"

Comment: It might look helpful to you "if we give u the code" (which it's actually not) but for sure it is not helpful to us. Please show us what you have tried and what your actual with that are.

Comment: select * from T1 where A=B group by c;

Answer (score 0):

If it's a SQL then maybe this is what you need:

```
select *
from T1
where (A=1 and B=1 and C=D) or (a<>1) or (b<>1)
```

but if it's plsql then:

```
DECLARE
  cursor c is
   select A,B,C,D from T1;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN c LOOP
    IF r.A = 1 AND r.B = 1 THEN
       IF r.C = r.D THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('YES!!!');
       ELSE
          dbms_output.put_line('Oh no ...');
       END IF;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```